# Can Excel charts be interactively zoomed and panned?

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I've always wanted this feature in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

I'm wondering if it's possible to develop a plugin or if one exists already?

Comment: What do you mean by "interactively?"

Comment: I mean you should be able to drag a box around the region of the chart you want to zoom in on instead of having to manually click on each axis and fiddling with the fixed scale.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They can if you use dynamic names ranges. Stephen Bullen has a great example [here](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/DLCount/DLCount.asp?file=FunChrt7.zip)

*Screenshot below*
The data can be zoomed (amount of data) and scrolled (change start position)

[image: funchart7]

Comment: It's far from ideal but it's better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: really? This is a pretty simple yet effective method. Your only other option being macros which is more cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, really. How do you see that working for an XY scatter plot? Seems pretty tedious to fool with scroll bars when drawing a box with the mouse would be much faster and easier. I'd like to see something interactive like ZedGraph in Excel: http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: The really was at the "better at nothing". You asked a one sentence question with little detail, your comment above is the first reference to XY scatter plot. Excel isn't and shouldn't be expected to be leading edge in all possible areas, this would start to overlap other software packages outside Excel's killer modelling abilities and it would unmanageable from Microsoft's perspective

Comment: Can you suggest another tool that combines spreadsheet data input with ZedGraph-like interactive charting? If not, thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

This might be irrelevant by now (seeing as it's been half a year), but: One improvement for Stephen Bullen's approach I would suggest is to map the scrollbar values to the actual values. What I mean is this: if you're fully zoomed out (you see everything), you can still scroll around which doesn't make sense. Additionally, if your dataset grows, you'd have to reformat the scrollbars max. values.
I solved it like this:

- Let both scrollbars assume values 1-1000.
- Let a specific cell contain the number of the last row of your dataset (can be formula-computed somehow, I guess) - I assume cell Z1 contains this information.
- Define a new name 'ActualZoomVal', let it point to an arbitrary cell. I assume Z2 here.
- Define a new name 'ActualScrollVal', let it point to a different arbitrary cell. I assume Z3 here.
- Let the cell of 'ActualZoomVal' contain following formula: =MAX(2;ROUND(ZoomVal*($Z$1/1000);0))
- Let the cell of 'ActualScrollVal' contain following formula: =ROUND(($Z$1-ActualZoomVal)*(ScrollVal/1000);0)
- Create the diagram as suggested in Stephen Bullen's example file, but with ActualZoomVal/ActualScrollVal instead of ZoomVal/ScrollVal

Not only is this a 'cleaner' and more flexible solution, it also improves usability - say you want to zoom in on the last part of the data set from a fully zoomed out state, then just set the scroll bar all the way to the right and keep zooming in until you've reached the desired zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution for zooming on Excel charts.  You add a zoom button to the chart, and pressing the button calls a macro to enlarge the chart by a specified amount.

The workbook containing the macro is available for free download at

http://www.excelcampus.com/vba/zoom-on-excel-charts

Comment: There are Excel add-ins available for dynamic zoom and scroll of charts.  
See following links and YouTube video
https://amitpora.wixsite.com/

Comment: Also https://youtu.be/dpCAhtnh458?si=oKcRN7YQv77kpE0p